# Range of the function $f(x)=\frac{2}{x^n+x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}...+\frac{1}{x^n}}$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have to find the range of the function $$f(x)=\frac{2}{x^n+x^{n-1}+...x^1+1+\frac{1}{x}+...+\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{x^n}}$$
I re wrote this as $$f(x)=\frac{2}{1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (x^k+\frac{1}{x^k})}$$
Differentiating the function as $$f'(x)=\frac{-2}{1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (x^k+\frac{1}{x^k})}\cdot \bigl[\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k (x^{k-1}-\frac{1}{x^{k+1}})\bigr]$$
I don't know how to proceed any further. I know that to find range of a function, we plot the function $f(x)$ by putting $f'(x)=0$, which solves for critical points of the function, and then we determine whether the function increases or decreases in various intervals. But in this problem I don't know how to solve for $f'(x)=0$. So I tried to plot at $x=0,\infty,-\infty$.
$f(x)$ at $x=+\infty$.
$$f(\infty)= \frac{2}{1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \infty^k +\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\infty^k}}=\frac{2}{1+\infty+0}=0
$$
Similarly, for $x=0:$
$$f(0)=\frac{2}{1+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n 0^k + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{0^k}} = \frac{2}{1+0+\infty} = 0
$$
For $x=-\infty$,
$$f(-\infty) = \frac{2}{1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-\infty)^k +\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (\frac{1}{-\infty})^k}=\frac{2}{1-\infty-0} =0
$$

I checked the plot of $f(x)$ in Desmos for few values of $n:$

[$f(x), n=5$][1]
[$f(x), n=6$][2]
[$f(x), n=7$][3]

I realised the maximum value of $f(x)$ for $x\in \mathbf R^+$ is at $x=0$. So,
$$f(1)= \frac{2}{1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 1^k +\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1^k}} = \frac{2}{1+2n}
$$
This is correct for the three graphs I plotted at $n=5,6,7$.
For $x\in \mathbf R^-, f(x)$ is either maximum at 2 (for odd n) or minimum at -2 (for even n). Solving for $f(-1)$
$$f(-1) = \frac{2}{1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^k +\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(-1)^k}}  = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{1-1-1} = -2&\text{n = odd}\\
\frac{2}{1+0+0} =2&\text{n = even}
\end{cases}
$$

So,the graph can be plotted if I know that the critical points are 1,-1, i.e., when $f'(x)=0$. But, I can't solve for $f'(x)=0$, as I showed above. So, how to know that 1, -1 are the critical points without solving for $f'(x)$? Is it a mere guess or just some observation I can't see?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukCfk.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEEgL.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikpmq.jpg

Comment: Hint: The denominator is a geometric series and can be simplified.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for such an observation, and such a quick reply. I completely missed it. The series has  r=x, so sum can be found only for |x|<1. I used the sum formula, and differentiated the function, but the expression turns ugly and I still can't solve it for 0. If I can somehow show that f'(x) is <0 for x<0 and >0 for x>0, then I can plot the region between -1<x<1. But what about values of x <-1 and x>1? Should I show that the series in the denominator diverges to infinity for |x|>1, so that f(x) -> 0 as x -> infinity ? And how to solve f'(x)=0 by using Geometric series formula?

Comment: An infinite geometric series converges only if $|r|<1$. A finite geometric series has an exact value no matter what.

Comment: for x>0, you can easily show that f(x)<f(1) since x+1/x>=2 for any x>0

Comment: Thanks @Mehdi ! But what about f(x) for -1<x<0? AM-GM inequality is applicable only for non-negative real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For x>0: $x^k + \frac{1}{x^k} \ge 2$ when equality holds for x=1. So,

If x>0 : $0<f(x) = \frac{2}{1+\sum_{k=1}^n {\left(x^k + \frac{1}{x^k}\right)} } \le \frac{2}{1+2n}$, with equality holds at $x=1$.

For analysis of f(x) at x<0, one can us geometric series we can write function as
$f(x) = \frac{2(x-1)x^{n}}{x^{2n+1}-1}$. Now we analyze $f(-x)$ at $x>0$.

$f(-x) = \frac{2(-x-1)(-x)^{n}}{-x^{2n+1}-1} ={(-1)}^n \frac{2(x+1)x^{n}}{x^{2n+1}+1} $.

Assume $g(x) = \frac{2(x+1)x^{n}}{x^{2n+1}+1},~x>0$. Now we just need to show that $0<g(x)\le2$ for $x>0$.

For $x>0$ it is obvious that $(x^{n+1}-1)(x^n-1)\ge0 \Rightarrow x^{2n+1}+1 \ge (x+1)x^{n}$ so $g(x)\le 2$.

Therefore, for n even we have
$f(-x) = g(x)~~ x>0 \Rightarrow 0<f(x)\le2$ for $x<0$.

for n odd

$f(-x) = -g(x) ~~ x>0 \Rightarrow -2\le f(x)<0$.

Hence, the range of f is $[-2,\frac{2}{1+2n}]$ for n odd and $[0,2]$ for n even.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks a lot. Just one thing: how did you decide to use $(x^{n+1} -1)(x^n-1) \geq 0$  to prove that $x^{2n+1}+1 \geq x^n(1+x)$  ? Did you reverse approach this inequality? It seems to be the only plausible reason to me, otherwise I can't guess something like that out of nowhere.

Comment: Yes reverse approach